# What common parlance best refers to a question "closed" under the new system?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I love the change from "Closed" to "On Hold," and it makes a lot of sense. Not going over that ground.

The problem I am seeing is that we *still* refer to "closing" a question in common parlance.  What is the best shorthand for getting rid of the "C" word?

Or, alternatively, is it correct to still refer to "closing" the question when it is on hold?

Comment: You don't. Because questions which are "on hold" are still on their way to being closed if nothing is done to prevent that.

Comment: They're being hel(le)d :-).

Comment: "Putting question on hold", maybe?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language. Try [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @hims056 I'd have to disagree. The question you linked to is a feature request, asking for text on the site to be changed. *This* question is asking how to refer to a question as on hold, which is a question of language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closed and on hold mean effectively the same thing, but 'closed' implies a false sense of finality. Closed questions can be improved and reopened if they're edited to fix whatever was wrong with them, at least the majority of them can. As you know the term didn't do a very good job of implying that.

The change does cause the eye to catch on questions that *obviously* will never be edited (asking about making pot roast on Stack Overflow), or people saying 'closed' within the amount of time that an edit from the OP could land it in the reopen review queue, which is actually 'on hold' (5 days).

While there *are* technical differences between the two terms (one's not *just* a euphemism), they are minute enough that they can pretty much be considered insignificant. If you want to use the most appropriate term, you could simply say "I'm voting to put this on hold" or "Your question was put on hold" where you would otherwise say 'close' or 'closed' respectively. Or, a moderator with a binding vote could say "I'm putting this on hold" instead of "closing".

But it's really just semantics that won't matter once a question gets a good edit and taken off hold, or reopened.

Answer (score 7):

It's still closed.

The only time you need to use that terminology is when talking to the OP, an then you can use phrases like "put on hold"/"putting it on hold" in place of words like "closed"/"closing".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we necessary need to get rid of the common parlance, but our usage should adjust to indicate that "closure" is a process that can be reversed. A "held" question is still closed, but finality of that is most in doubt in the first few hours or days of a question's lifetime. That is when having the `[on hold]` nomenclature in the subject and auto-generated messages is the most effective. It conveys the need for action.